# Estructurar un Array

Tags: javascript, vscode

Tengo este codigo:

```
const lista = (stores, shoppingList) =>{
    const Array = []
    const Articulos = []
        Object.entries(stores).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            Object.entries(value).forEach(([keys, values]) => {
                const a = shoppingList.find(elemento => elemento == keys);
                if(a != undefined){
                    const valor ={
                        Tienda: key, 
                        Articulo: keys, 
                        Precio: values
                    }
                    Array.push(valor)
                }
            });
        });
return Array
}


console.log(lista(stores, shoppingList))
```

***que me retorna este array:***

```
   [ { Tienda: 'd1', Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3500 },
  { Tienda: 'd1', Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 800 },
  { Tienda: 'd1', Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8000 },
  { Tienda: 'olimpica', Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3600 },
  { Tienda: 'olimpica', Articulo: 'papitasPollo', Precio: 3500 },
  { Tienda: 'olimpica', Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 850 },
  { Tienda: 'olimpica', Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8010 },
  { Tienda: 'exito', Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3650 },
  { Tienda: 'exito', Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 790 },
  { Tienda: 'exito', Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8000 },
  { Tienda: 'exito', Articulo: 'gomitas', Precio: 4520 },
  { Tienda: 'otra', Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3700 },
  { Tienda: 'otra', Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 7000 },
  { Tienda: 'otra', Articulo: 'gomitas', Precio: 4320 } ]
```

y necesito que se vea de esta forma:

```
[ { Tiendas: 
        d1: [
               { Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3500 },
                   { Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 800 },
                       { Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8000 }
],
    olimpica:[
      {Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3600 },
      {Articulo: 'papitasPollo', Precio: 3500 },
      { Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 850 },
      {Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8010 }
     ],
      exito:[
      { Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3650 },
      {  Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 790 },
      {  Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8000 },
      {  Articulo: 'gomitas', Precio: 4520 }
],
    otra:[
      { Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3700 },
      { Tienda: 'otra', Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 7000 },
      { Tienda: 'otra', Articulo: 'gomitas', Precio: 4320 }
 ]
]
```

Aqui les dejo los arrays:

```
const stores = {
    d1: {
        papitasBQ: 3500,
        papitasLimon: 3200,
        mani: 800,
        cafe: 8000,
        azucar: 3500,
        papel: 3000,
    },
    olimpica: {
        papitasBQ: 3600,
        papitasPollo: 3500,
        mani: 850,
        cafe: 8010,
        azucar: 3200,
        papel: 3500,
    },
    exito: {
        papitasBQ: 3650,
        papitasLimon: 3200,
        mani: 790,
        cafe: 8000,
        azucar: 3500,
        papel: 3000,
        gomitas: 4520,
    },
    otra: {
        papitasBQ: 3700,
        papitasLimon: 3200,
        cafe: 7000,
        azucar: 3000,
        papel: 3200,
        gomitas: 4320,
    },
};

const shoppingList = ['papitasPollo','papitasBQ','cafe','gomitas','mani']
```

> Uso un `plugin` llamado `Quokka` para hacerlo funcionar en la `consola` de
> `VSCode`

***Advertencia:***

> Al momento de instalarlo este necesita `Node.js`; por defecto viene en el `plugin` la `version 16.14` de `Node.js` este lo toma desde la web; si ya tienen instalado `Node.js` tienen que configurar el `plugin` para que tome el `Node.js` de su equipo porque si no lo hacen generara conflicto.

Comment: Yo no entendí... si el array de `shoppingList` tiene `"papitasLimon"`... como sabes al final de que tienda lo compró para obtener el resultado que deseas?

Comment: @Pipe por el key, este caso estoy haciendo un object.entries  que toma el key y el value del objeto y despues recorro el values nuevamente con el object.entries para que de esta forma me tome el key que serian los articulos y el value el precio de ellos, estoy usando una forma de "Destruccion de arrays" para poder recorrerlo mas facil lo encuentras en la documentacion

Comment: No uses `Array` como nombre de variable, ya que estás pisando el [Objeto Global Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de JavaScript.

Comment: Ademas el resultado que esperas, el que pusiste en la pregunta, esta mal tiene una llave ahi que no se cierra, que buscas un array de arrays con objetos dentro o que es lo que buscas?

Comment: Ya están las respuestas que pueden usar en este caso la respuesta que coloque es mucho mas eficiente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de realizarlo de manera mas rápida seria esta:

```
const findShoppingCart = (stores, shoppingList) => {
    //Se crea el objeto
    const result = {}

        Object.entries(stores).forEach(([store, items]) => {
            //Se crean las clave del objeto y 
            result[store] = {
                items: [],
                total: 0
            }
            Object.entries(items).forEach(([item, price]) => {
                if(shoppingList.includes(item)) {
                    //Se añaden los valores 
                    result[store].total += price
                    result[store].items.push({
                        [item]: price
                    })
                }
            });
        });

        return result
}


console.log(findShoppingCart(stores, shoppingList))
```

es mucho mas secillo, sin usar metodos ni nada solo recorrerlo, buscar si existe o no, crear una clave asigarlo y demas espero que pueda ser de ayuda ya que no encontre esta forma en internet

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas una función reductora sobre el resultado actual. De esta forma podrás agrupar los elementos tal como los quieres.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const lista = (stores, shoppingList) => {
    const array = [];
    const articulos = [];
        Object.entries(stores).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            Object.entries(value).forEach(([keys, values]) => {
                const a = shoppingList.find(elemento => elemento == keys);
                if(a){
                    array.push({
                        Tienda: key, 
                        Articulo: keys, 
                        Precio: values
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    return array.reduce((acc, curr) => {  // función reductora
      if(!acc[curr.Tienda]) {
        acc[curr.Tienda] = [];
      }
      const { Articulo, Precio } = curr;
      acc[curr.Tienda].push({ Articulo, Precio });
      return acc;
    }, {});  // <= objeto inicial vacío
}

const stores = {
    d1: {
        papitasBQ: 3500,
        papitasLimon: 3200,
        mani: 800,
        cafe: 8000,
        azucar: 3500,
        papel: 3000,
    },
    olimpica: {
        papitasBQ: 3600,
        papitasPollo: 3500,
        mani: 850,
        cafe: 8010,
        azucar: 3200,
        papel: 3500,
    },
    exito: {
        papitasBQ: 3650,
        papitasLimon: 3200,
        mani: 790,
        cafe: 8000,
        azucar: 3500,
        papel: 3000,
        gomitas: 4520,
    },
    otra: {
        papitasBQ: 3700,
        papitasLimon: 3200,
        cafe: 7000,
        azucar: 3000,
        papel: 3200,
        gomitas: 4320,
    },
};

const shoppingList = ['papitasPollo','papitasBQ','cafe','gomitas','mani'];

console.log(lista(stores, shoppingList))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

El método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) del objeto global Array, toma 2 argumentos: una función reductora y un elemento inicial (opcional).

En tu caso, la función reductora se limita a añadir a una lista (identificada por el nombre de la tienda) los productos que pertenecen a la misma. Para ello, primero crea una lista vacía, si la tienda en cuestión no existe en el objeto inicial.

```js
// Toma el valor de "Tienda" del elemento actual (curr)
if(!acc[curr.Tienda]) {
  acc[curr.Tienda] = []; // crea una entrada en el objeto con el valor adecuado
}
```

Luego por cada elemento de la lista original, va añadiendo los datos que quieres a la lista que representa a la tienda.

```js
const { Articulo, Precio } = curr;
acc[curr.Tienda].push({ Articulo, Precio });
```

Por último, devuelve el objeto acumulado para la siguiente iteración.

**NOTA**

Cabe destacar que lo que muestras como resultado deseado no es un Objeto válido en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```js
[ { Tiendas: // falta un delimitador
        d1: [
               { Articulo: 'papitasBQ', Precio: 3500 },
                   { Articulo: 'mani', Precio: 800 },
                       { Articulo: 'cafe', Precio: 8000 }
],
```

En todo caso, puedes ver el resultado parecido a lo que quieres haciendo lo siguiente en la linea de `return` de tu función:

```js
return {
  Tiendas: array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // ...
  }, {})
};
```

Que te devolverá:

```js
{ 
  Tiendas: {
    d1: [ ... ],
    olimpica: [ ... ],
    //...
  }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.